# Symfony formtype add query builder from another entity

Tags: php, sql, symfony

anyone know if I can put sql query in a formtype?
I created a function and now I want to call it in the builder, but it asks me to pass an argument

```php
 public function hoursCalendar(ParametresRepository $repoParam){

        $hours = $repoParam->find(1);
        $minHours = $hours->getCalendarStartTime();
        $maxHours = $hours->getCalendarEndTime();
        $range = range($minHours , $maxHours);

        return $range;

    } 


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       
            $this->hoursCalendar();

            $var = 15;  

        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('start', DateTimeType::class, [
                'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                'time_widget' => 'choice',
                'hours' => range( $var, 18),
                'minutes' => [ 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55
                ],
            ])
            ->add('end', DateTimeType::class, [
                'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                'time_widget' => 'single_text'
            ])
            ->add('description')
            ->add('resource')
            ->add('all_day')
            ->add('background_color', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Type de RDV',
                'choices' => array(
                    'Client' => "#800000",
                    'Formation' => "#ADD8E6"),
                    ))
            ->add('border_color', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'User',
                'choices' => array(
                    'Bart' => "#000000",
                    'Loic' => "#00FF00"),
                    ))
            ->add('text_color', ColorType::class)
            

        ;
    }
```

In the end, what I want is to do is put the information I have in calendarStartTime and calendarEndTime to replace the values in the range of the 'hours': range (calendarStartTime, calendarEndTime),

Thanks

Comment: Inject `ParametresRepository` in the constructor and you have it

Answer (score 0):

Inject `ParametresRepository` in the constructor:

```php
private $repoParam;

public function __construct(ParametresRepository $repoParam)
{
    $this->repoParam = $repoParam;
}
```

then no need for the parameter in `hoursCalendar`:

```php
public function hoursCalendar()
{
    $hours = $this->repoParam->find(1);
    $minHours = $hours->getCalendarStartTime();
    $maxHours = $hours->getCalendarEndTime();
    $range = range($minHours , $maxHours);

    return $range;
}
```